# combining strings using string substitution - python

Tags: python, syntax

hey guys, i want to perform the following operation:

```
b = 'random'

c = 'stuff'

a  = '%s' + '%s' %(b, c)
```

but i get the following error:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

does any one of you know to do so ?

Comment: lol, never mind, i just figured it out , dumb mistake :D

Comment: i was trying to use the %s format specifier, but i had forgotten that %b%c, is the same as b + c

Comment: `%` has a higher precedence than `+` so the compiler reads it as `'%s' + ( '%s' % (b, c) )` which fails as there is only one pattern for two values.

Comment: Kind of Python newbie myself, but would not `a = ('%s' + '%s') % (b, c)` also work? Because this seems to be just an operator precedence problem...

Comment: @rsenna: Yes, because the `('%s' + '%s')` will combine into `('%s%s')`. Declaring `('%s%s')` is the same as `'%s%s'`, so you end up with the same thing as `'%s%s' % (b, c)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you want :

```
>>> b = 'random'
>>> c = 'stuff'
>>> a  = '%s' %b + '%s' % c
>>> a
'randomstuff'
>>> 

>>> b + c
'randomstuff'
>>> 
>>> z = '%s + %s' % (b, c)
>>> z
'random + stuff'
>>>
```

Comment: wow, thanks guys, i didn't know about the precedence part , i ended up doing it like : a = '%b%c' %(b,c)

Comment: @paulo: If all you're doing is concatenating strings, *please* just use `+`.  Simple and clear.

Comment: @Nick T: @paulo: The reason, I simply showed the various examples was that the intent of the code in question was not clear. The advices in the various replies and comments holds. If you are concatenating, do it directly, for formatting use "%" approach and even better the 'format' as suggested by sdolan.

Answer (score 4):

```
'%s%s' % (b, c)
```

or

```
b + c
```

or the newstyle `format` way

```
'{0}{1}'.format(a, b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to operator precedence, your program is first trying to substitue b and c into second '%s'. Therefore splitting such strings with + is meaningless, it's better to do
`a = '%s %s' % (b,c)`